# Clean document fromspecial char in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, special-characters

I'm trying to clean all document from a special chars, but something not working as well.

My field `descrizione` contains some special chars. In this case **`^`** and **`-`**:

> ^CT 6 STP ANTIPERDITE OLIO MOT BENZ-DIE

```js
    db.Collection.find({descrizione: /[$&+,:;=?@#|<>.^*()%!-]/g}).forEach(function(doc) {
        doc.descrizione = doc.descrizione.replace(/[$&+,:;=?@#|<>.^*()%!-]/g,"");
        db.Collection.update({ "_id": doc._id },{ "$set": { "descrizione": doc.descrizione } });
    });
```

but something not working as well

This is my document: (Mongo Version 3.4.1)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60f028bda2255f376aedeb7f"),
    "id_am" : "0124525046",
    "id_kromeda" : "0124525046",
    "descrizione" : "Alternatore",
    "prezzo" : "334.60",
    "classe" : "200",
    "campo_a" : "BOSCH VARI 2",
    "campo_b" : "BOSCH VARI 2",
    "produttore" : "BOSCH VARI 2",
    "prezzo_officine" : "421.60",
    "rincaro" : "0%",
    "cod_listino" : "027",
    "cod_produttore" : "0124525046",
    "unita_acquisto" : "1",
    "pezzi_unita" : "NR",
    "is_enabled" : true,
    "cd_type" : "SPARE"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Aggregation` pipeline with 2 `$set` stages. In each stage filter out one special character with `$replaceAll`.

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      descrizione: {
        $replaceAll: {
          input: "$descrizione",
          find: "^",
          replacement: ""
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      descrizione: {
        $replaceAll: {
          input: "$descrizione",
          find: "-",
          replacement: ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AdcXs9NYYLD)

Comment: I get back this error: Wrong type for 'u'. Expected a object, got a array.

Comment: Add your code to the question. Maybe you have some syntax error.

Comment: Done, added in question :) my mongo version is 3.4.1

Comment: Not document, but code. Check to working example, it works with your document as well.

Comment: i use your query in Robo3T and give me back the error

Comment: I don't know much about Robo3T, sorry.